# reset() method for resetting form fields results in errors

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using ngForm in html and in typescript implemented resetting form fields in OnCickSubmit(). It performs as expected and thus does clear the form's select field but resetting also seems to show 400 bad errors for api calls behind populating the form fields.Eg:dataChanged() is actually calling api in back-end to populate the field and after successful submit then reset happens which clears field but why is the function called again and indeed api called again. Is there a way to avoid this?

html :

```
<form id = "myForm" #myForm = "ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "onClickSubmit(myForm.value)">  
 <label>Name</label>&nbsp;
    <select ngModel name= "cname" (ngModelChange)="dataChanged($event)" required>
      <option [ngValue]="data.name" *ngFor = "let data of result">{{data.name}}</option>
    </select><br/>
 <input class = "button" align = "center" type = "submit" value = "Apply" [disabled]="!myForm.valid"><br/>
</form>
```

In typescript onClickSubmit():

```
anotherfunc();
var resetForm = <HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById("myForm");
resetForm.reset();
```

Comment: Not enough info to know what's going on. Also that is not the correct method to access your `Form`, you should be using `NgForm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I able to understand your problem properly, don't use `getElementById` to form reset in angular. we can do form reset in other ways and they are lot simpler than this.

do some changes in your component and template  like below

**yourComponent.html**

```
<form id = "myForm" #myForm = "ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "onClickSubmit(myForm.value)">  
 <label>Name</label>&nbsp;
    <select [(ngModel)]="dataName" name= "cname" (ngModelChange)="dataChanged($event)" required>
      <option [ngValue]="data.name" *ngFor = "let data of result">{{data.name}}</option>
    </select><br/>
 <button class = "button" align = "center" type = "submit" value = "Apply" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">submit</button><br/>
</form>
```

**yourComponent.ts**

```
dataName: string;

onClickSubmit(event: any){
  // this.service.sendPost(){  <= call your method here 
     on successful response clear the form 
   if(data.status == 200)
     this.dataName = undefined;

  //}
}
```

your using input for submitting the form, it's recommended to use button for that. I changed it in html

Comment: setting the variables as undefined does solve part of the problem(no longer failed api calls or func calls on successful submit) but it makes the <select> fields in form as un-selectable, so the user won't have the ability to select /test things in form again as it clears the whole populated drop-downs rather than setting to its initial state.

Comment: we are setting `ngModel` value to `undefined` and we are not setting the result array to `undefined`. So this gives the ability to select the things again from the dropdown. So just set ngModel to undefined not the whole array which we are using as options in select dropdown.

Comment: thanks @ganesh045 my bad, I didn't understand that here you're trying to perform two-way binding for the form.

Comment: glad to help you :)